# Operations on byte are atomic in C++11?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, atomic

So does operations on char are atomic?
So in thread A I read char T and in thread B I write on same char T, are these standard operations atomic?

```
char a;

#thread A
{ 
if(a & 0x01)
  ...

}

#thread B
{ 
 a =0x01;
  ...

}

# ATOMIC?
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the C++ standard, potentially-concurrent access happens when the same variable is used from multiple threads, and these accesses *conflict* if at least one access is a write.

Potentially-concurrent accesses that conflict constitutes a *data race*, which is undefined behavior unless all such accesses are atomic.  `volatile` will not save you.

**Primitive types are not *atomic* within the meaning used in the C++ standard**.  You can use the `std::atomic` template to make objects which are atomic.